# Serializing specified fields with JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm building a REST API and I would like to give my users a possibility to choose which fields to return via a URL parameter, e.g

```
/users?fields=username,email,address.city,address.country
```

Is there any way to accomplish such functionality with JMSSerializerBundle?

// EDIT

Please note the embedded collections

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this the job for `JMSSerializer`, at least no entirely. Instead, what I would do is:

```
// Do not serialize into JSON or XML, but to PHP array
$userSerialized = $jmsSerializer->toArray($user);

// Turn "username,email" into ['username' => 0, 'email' => 1, ... ]
$fields = array_flip(explode($request->query->get('fields')));

$userSerializedFiltered = array_intersect_key($userSerialized, $fields);

// Finally, put it into desired format, JSON for example:
$json = json_encode($userSerializedFiltered);
```

### Another idea:

You could utilize [Doctrine Partial objects](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html):

```
$user = $em->createQuery("select partial u.{" . $fields . "} from MyApp\Domain\User u")->getResult();
$serialized = $jmsSerializer->serialize($user, 'json');
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Although, if you want a more generic solution for all the entities, this won't work as you need to repeat the logic...

Comment: I've been thinking of something similar but it just seems nasty to load the fully serialized data into memory and then reduce it instead of just getting the reduced data

Comment: Aha, so here is an idea: JSMSerializer, by default, skips `NULL` values. If you could load your entity as partial object you could achieve just that.

Comment: This approach seems kind of hacky BUT.... it has this additional benefit that it will select less columns from the database and save some memory / speed up queries :-) . I'll think about this solution for a minute

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: This answer only covers the initial question which didn't ask for deeper levels of serialization. I'll keep it anyway as it might help others struggling with that initial question as well.

We did exactly the same in a pretty generic way.

We extended the **ViewHandler** to read from the current **Request** if 'fields' has been attached as a parameter and added a **ExclusionStrategy** to the **SerializationContext**.

It's worth to notice that this approach is working with FOS Rest Bundle 1.7.7 (we didn't migrate to the newest JMS version so far), Symfony > 2.8 and JMSSerializerBundle 1.1.0 - but it shouldn't be too hard to migrate this approach to any other combination as well.

```
class ViewHandler extends \FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler
{
/**
 * Extends ViewHandler, adds the exclusion strategies FieldListExclusionStrategy to the SerializationContext.
 *
 * Reads Request Parameter "fields" (comma separated list) and parses it into an array. Does some clean-up on parameter
 */
protected function getSerializationContext(View $view)
{
    $context = $view->getSerializationContext();
    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

    if ($request->isMethod('GET') && $request->query->has('fields')) {
        $fieldList = explode(',', $request->query->get('fields'));

        array_walk($fieldList, array(&$this, 'cleanString'));   //clean special characters except - and _
        $fieldList = array_filter($fieldList);                  // remove empty elements

        $context->addExclusionStrategy(new FieldListExclusionStrategy($fieldList));
    }

    $view->setSerializationContext($context);

    return parent::getSerializationContext($view);
}


/**
 * Helper to remove special characters from String, Compatible with array_walk
 *
 * @param string $string -
 * @param mixed  $key    -needed to be compatible with array_walk without raising a notice. (hands in 2 parameters)
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
private function cleanString(&$string, $key)
{
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\_]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

    return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
}
}
```

And this is the FieldListExclusionStrategy Class:

```
class FieldListExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategyInterface
{
/**
 * @var array
 */
private $fields = array();
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $maxDepth;

/**
 * FieldListExclusionStrategy constructor.
 *
 * @param array $fields
 */
public function __construct(array $fields)
{
    $this->maxDepth = 1;
    $this->fields = $fields;
}

/**
 * Whether the class should be skipped.
 *
 * @param ClassMetadata $metadata
 * @param Context       $context
 * @return boolean
 */
public function shouldSkipClass(ClassMetadata $metadata, Context $context)
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Whether the property should be skipped.
 *
 * @param PropertyMetadata $property
 * @param Context          $context
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function shouldSkipProperty(PropertyMetadata $property, Context $context)
{
    if (0 === count($this->fields)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($context->getDepth() > $this->maxDepth) {
        return false;
    }

    $name = $property->serializedName ?: $property->name;

    return !in_array($name, $this->fields, true);
}
}
```

Comment: Nice "prototype" but it looks like it won't work with embedded collections

Comment: it's a "prototype" we're successfully using since over two years now. sorry, but you're question doesn't ask for collections - this is indeed missing in our solution currently (we handle that differently), but it should be feasible with this approach as well.

Comment: given your question this answer is perfectly fine. how would you ask for collections in your request? something like /users?fields=username,email,adress.city or what do you mean?

Comment: that's making a hure difference here - but can you tell me why my approach shouldn't be feasible here? and where do you stop? what about: /users?fields=username,email,adress.region.country.countryISO?

Comment: That's also a problem I've been thinking of. I think there should be some kind of map that you pass when serializing data (or just a simple array) so the serializer will ignore the fields that are not specified in the map. I don't know how to implement it with JMSSerializerBundle though as I'm kind of new to it. You probably need to add an exclusion strategy but I don't know how to make it work with the map

Comment: so, carefully read my code - you can extend it that way. but i don't recommend to do it, you'll have to mention all fields (which can get a rather long list) as part of a result.

Comment: Let's say that I have project.name, project.minorProgrammer.name and project.majorProgrammer.name. How will I know where I'm currently at in the exclusion strategy?

Comment: Like... how will I know if I'm currently inside of project or, for example, inside of project.majorProgrammer ?

Comment: Last comment: This isn't easy, yes. And that's why I said I don't recommend your approach (and you don't find any prebuilt solutions). We're using groups and a lot of other stuff, the 'fields' approach we're only using for simple exclusions. Btw: Extending your question with every comment isn't a really fair way.

Comment: So your recommendation is to include / exclude properties only on the main object and always include the embedded objects in their default form?